# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{4}} \frac{x^2}{\left(2\sqrt{x} - 1\right)^2}$

Tags: limits, factoring, limits-without-lhopital

How can I calculate this limit?

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{4}} \frac{x^2}{\left(2\sqrt{x} - 1\right)^2}$$

I know that it is $+\infty$ as I saw answers from online calculators, but they always use exponential and logs or L'hopital's rule. Is there another way of solving it (factoring or rationalising)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the numerator converge to? And the denominator? What can you conclude?

Comment: For what it's worth, the hypothesis of L'Hopital's rule prevents its use in this case.

Comment: You may solve it by direct substitution.

Comment: The numerator in this case is 1/16 as x approaches 1/4. The denominator is 0+ because ((2√x)-1)=0 and as it is squared, it is positive, thus 0+. And as the rule in front of me says, the limit of a positive number over 0+ is +∞.

Comment: By direct substitution it's constant/0 not 0/0

Comment: Thank you Utkarsh. I didn't notice that.

Comment: @ZackHammer remember that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} = +\infty$ while $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-} \frac{1}{x} = -\infty$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align} \lim_{x \to \frac{1}{4}} \frac{x^2}{\left(2\sqrt{x} - 1\right)^2}&\\&=\frac{(\frac{1}{4})^2}{\left(2\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}} - 1\right)^2}\\ &=\frac{\frac{1}{16}}{\left(2\cdot\frac{1}{2} - 1\right)^2}\\ &=\frac{\frac{1}{16}}{\left(1 - 1\right)^2}\\ &=\frac{\frac{1}{16}}{0^+}\\&=\frac{1}{0^+} \end{align}$$

This quantity will appoach $+\infty$.

See the graph

[image]